# C# Flags enum Understanding

Tags: enums, flags

please help! Im trying to make out the following code but i cant understand it. Can someone make me understand it? specialy this code segment:

```
MyEnum d2 = (MyEnum)code.
```

My code:

```
public struct MyStruct
        {
            public bool HaveHours;
            public List<int> Hours;
            public List<int>Mins;
            public MyStruct(string code) : this(((string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) == false) ? long.Parse(code) : -1)) { }

            public MyStruct(long code)
            {

                this.HaveHours = false;
                this.Hours = new List<int>();
                this.Mins = new List<int>();
                if (code != -1)
                {
                    this.HaveHours = true;
                    MyEnum d2 = (MyEnum)code;

                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h0) == MyEnum.h0) this.Hours.Add(0);

                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h030) == MyEnum.h030) this.Mins.Add(0);

                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h1) == MyEnum.h1) this.Hours.Add(1);
                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h130) == MyEnum.h130) this.Mins.Add(1);

                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h2) == MyEnum.h2) this.Hours.Add(2);
                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h230) == MyEnum.h230) this.Mins.Add(2);

                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h3) == MyEnum.h3) this.Hours.Add(3);
                    if ((d2 & MyEnum.h330) == MyEnum.h330) this.Mins.Add(3);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: `code` is a `long` integer value that is cast to an enum value to see if it matches any particular named value (which is what an `enum` is, ultimately). What part about it don't you understand?

Comment: thanx for the quick answer! yes that part didnt understand! can i cast int to enum? and if yes how or what will d2&myenum.h0 ie match?

Answer (score 0):

The flag enums basically works as a binary number (e.g. 100110101) where every bit has a meaning. By using MyEnum (I assume) it is possible to access these bits formations by certain names (e.g. h330).
When you cast the long number into the enum you cast a number into its binary flag enum (that is just a representation for you for the machine everything is binary).
The rest of the code checks if certain flags are on (bit values are 1) according to the enum values.
Hope that helps.

Comment: thanx for the reply..if i realy get it i can say if f.e code=16 ,then d2 will get the value= h2! right? MyEnum ist a flag!